# What is this creeping plant?

Tags: identification, berries

This plant has berry like things and grows on the hilly areas of Northern India on the foothills of the Himalayas.
Haven’t tasted the berries as it might be poisonous. Also it also grows by hanging on to other trees.
[image]

Comment: Can you include more pictures, eg from different sides of the berries, close-up of the leaves? Also, a cross-section of a berry might be useful, to see if it has seeds or a stone, etc.

Comment: I do not have any more pictures, sorry

Answer (score 1):

This might be a purple chokeberry.  Ive read they grow in wet woodlands and swamps.  Not sure where that one was growing.

Comment: No, it wasn’t growing on a wetland and not on a swamp either

Comment: Also the leaves are completely different and this plant in the question is a creeping plant